# How to sort a String and check for anagrams?

Tags: java, sorting, selection-sort, anagram

I'm supposed to write an algorithm that tests two Strings to check if they're anagrams of each other and I have to use either BubbleSort, SelectionSort or InsertionSort.
So I used SelectionSort to sort the Strings, which I converted to char arrays beforehand, but it doesn't work and I cannot find my mistake.

```
public static void selectionSort(char[] arr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        int least = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[least])
                least = j;
            if (least != i) {
                int swap = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[least];
                arr[least] = (char) swap;

            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean anagramCheck(String x, String y) {

    x.trim();
    y.trim();

    x.toLowerCase();
    y.toLowerCase();

    char xarr[] = x.toCharArray();
    char yarr[] = y.toCharArray();

    if (x.length() != y.length())
        return false;

    selectionSort(xarr);
    System.out.println(xarr); // I used this to check if the Strings are sorted correctly
    selectionSort(yarr);
    System.out.println(yarr);

    if (xarr == yarr) {
        System.out.println("It's an anagram.");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to ignore capital letters and spaces, that's why I used trim() and toLowerCase(). But it neither trims the spaces nor changes capital letters to lower case letters. Additionally, when I use more than 5 letters, it doesn't sort the given Strings alphabetically. Only one of both is sorted correctly, the other one is messed up.
I am new to Java programming so I might need some help here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. But I used bubbleSort

```
class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(anagramCheck("listen", "silent"));
  }
  public static boolean anagramCheck(String x, String y) {

    x = x.trim();
    y = y.trim();

    x = x.toLowerCase();
    y = y.toLowerCase();

    char xarr[] = x.toCharArray();
    char yarr[] = y.toCharArray();

    if (x.length() != y.length())
       return false;

    x = bubbleSort(xarr);
    System.out.println(xarr); // I used this to check if the Strings are sorted correctly

    y = bubbleSort(yarr);
    System.out.println(yarr);

    if (x.equals(y)) {
       System.out.println("It's an anagram.");
       return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
   }

   public static String bubbleSort(char[] arr) {

    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                // swap arr[j+1] and arr[j]
                char temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return String.valueOf(arr);
  }

}
```

Comment: x = x.trim();
y = y.trim();

x = x.toLowerCase();
y = y.toLowerCase();

Comment: as soon as theres a space inbetween two letters it doesn't work anymore, e.g. "Anagram" and "Nag ar am" isn't considered an anagram anymore

Answer (score 0):

Check where I did the modification:

```
public static void selectionSort(char[] arr) {

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    int least = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[j] < arr[least])
            least = j;
    }
    if (least != i) {
         int swap = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[least];
         arr[least] = (char) swap;

    }
  }
}
```

In `anagramCheck` function:

```
x = x.trim(); // it returns trim string
y = y.trim();
x = x.toLowerCase(); // return lower-case string
y = y.toLowerCase();
```